# ValueError: y contains non binary labels for VotingClassifier with my GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

Hi I am trying to use VotingClassifier with my GradientBoostingClassifier that I put a wrapper around in order to make use of sample_weight. 
However, I got the below error and can't figure out how to fix it.

The code:

```
class MyGradientBoostingClassifier(GradientBoostingClassifier):
    def fit(self, X , y=None):
        return super(GradientBoostingClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight=y)


rf =  RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
mygb = MyGradientBoostingClassifier()

vc = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('rf', rf), ('mygb', mygb)],
                        voting='soft',
                        weights=[1,2])

mygb.fit(X5, y5)
```

Sample piece of y is `[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]` and it's np array

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-c56d4cac146f> in <module>()
     13                         weights=[1,2])
     14 
---> 15 mygb.fit(X5, y5)

<ipython-input-62-c56d4cac146f> in fit(self, X, y)
      3         print np.shape(y), np.shape(X), Counter(y), type(y)
      4         print y[:20]
----> 5         return super(GradientBoostingClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight=y)
      6 
      7 

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, monitor)
    987 
    988             # fit initial model - FIXME make sample_weight optional
--> 989             self.init_.fit(X, y, sample_weight)
    990 
    991             # init predictions

/Users/a/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    117 
    118         if neg == 0 or pos == 0:
--> 119             raise ValueError('y contains non binary labels.')
    120         self.prior = self.scale * np.log(pos / neg)
    121 

ValueError: y contains non binary labels.
```

Answer (score 1):

For classification models `y` is expected to be an integer class label (0 and 1) therefore it does not make sense to use it both as the target for classification and as a sample weight.

All the samples with 0 weight are ignore with the model and it is not possible to train a binary classification model only with sample from the same single class of the training set.

Comment: Hi ogrisel, thanks for the comment. So do you mean that I shouldn't use sample weight in this case? Could you give me more detailed suggestion?

Comment: Just deleted my answer as it might be confusing, @ogrisel is right

Comment: Could someone clarify what ogrisel explains?

Comment: You can use sample weights but you should pass real weights, not the target class labels. Otherwise you put a weight of zero to all the samples with class label 0, which cause the model to just ignore those samples and only keep the samples with class labels 1. Read the docstring for the parameters sample_weight.